# dispatch an action through connect I am getting an error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

- I am new to redux and trying to learn everything from scratch.
- so I took an npm package and implementing in my form
- when I try to dispatch an action through connect I am getting an error Maximum call stack size exceeded
- without connect it was working fine.
- can you let me know how to fix it. I looked into both the documentaion
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar
  https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013
- I debugged by putting console but still I am not able to fix it.
- can you tell me how to fix so that infuture I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zn812n05v4

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  console.log("mapDispatchToProps--->", dispatch);
  return {
    fetchHistoryBenchmarkDatafromURL: () => {
      dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar"));
      // dispatch(fetchHistoryBenchmarkDatafromURL());
    }
  };
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "syncValidation", // a unique identifier for this form
  validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
  warn // <--- warning function given to redux-form
})(connect(mapDispatchToProps)(SyncValidationForm));
```

error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at runBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:150)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:47)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `dispatch` during the middle of rendering. The following line from `SyncValidationForm` is going to trigger a change to the redux state, which will trigger re-rendering, which will re-execute this line changing state again, etc.

store.dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar"));

Comment: can you tell me how you figured out this line is the problem since when Ilooked at the error it didnt point to the particular file...it pointed to library files...it would be great if you let me know so that in future I will fix it myself

Comment: I didn’t look at the error. You mentioned in your question that adding the dispatch of an action caused the problem which meant you were likely dispatching from rendering so I glanced through your rendering functions.

Comment: Just now I looked at the error, and if you scroll down you can see the following: SyncValidationForm
/SyncValidationForm.js:60:8
  57 | console.log("handleSubmit--->", handleSubmit);
  58 | console.log("handleSubmit props--->", props);
  59 | //props.dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar"));
> 60 | store.dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar"));
     |      ^
  61 | return (
  62 |   <div>
  63 |     <LoadingBar scope="sectionBar" />

Comment: can you tell me why its referrring to this files PooledClass.js, ReactUpdates.js, Transaction.js if it refers to this file SyncValidationForm.js  I can easily find out its due to the dispatch line...lot of times I have faced similar type of issues...if you let me know for this one then in future I can fix it myself :(

Comment: In general, whenever you see a large stack trace where the first entries are deep within library code, you should scroll through it carefully till you see an entry that points at something in your own code.

Comment: I updated the error but still I dont see the SyncValidationForm.js in the error...am I see seeing something wrong :(

Comment: Now the stack trace looks a little different than the one I saw earlier. One thing that is consistent is the warnings in the console prior to the error that say: "Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`"

Comment: hey but warnings also doesnt poibnt to this file SyncValidationForm.js then how can I gues a particular line number in that file

Comment: By knowing what you changed that caused the error to appear. By looking at the text of the warning and looking for where in your code you are doing what it says you shouldn't be doing. By simplifying the code as much as possible till you remove something that causes the error to disappear.

Comment: can you help me with tgis one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084760/file-merge-using-react-in-material-ui